# Display fermata before bar line

Tags: lilypond

I am typesetting a score where one of the parts (*Carmen*, horns, number 15) reads, in this order:

(multi-measure rest) (fermata) (bar line)

I tried the following:

```
R4*17 <>\fermata
```

This correctly displays a fermata after the multi-measure rest, but inserts a bar line before the fermata. How would it be possible to insert the fermata before the bar line?

(I also tried `R4*17\fermata`, but obviously this puts the fermata right over the rest, which is not what I need either).

Comment: It would be great NOT to do this. How does the person counting the multimeasure rest know where the fermata falls? (Aside from the fact that everybody knows Carmen.) Either don't bother to mention it, or break up the rest. As a player, I'm a big fan of seeing rests broken up to show rehearsal numbers or cues.

Comment: @AndyBonner If I saw this notation, I would assume the fermata comes at the end of the multi-measure rest time and that the following bar is queued.

Comment: Uh ... cued. (I mean, also queued, technically, but ....)

Comment: @AndyBonner Of course I only do this with the fermata at the end, otherwise I would have split the multimeasure rest.

Comment: @Circonflexe: I would expect that the fermatta would fall in the last measure, and watching the conductor would make it clear where it fell (e.g. if it fell on a dotted half note, and was followed by a two-eighth-note anacrusis, someone watching the director would be able to tell that the downbeat of the next measure would come after the anacrusus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\override MultiMeasureRestScript.parent-alignment-X = 1`

This will cause the fermata to be placed at the right edge of its parent.

For example, the following code:

```
\score {
  \relative c' {
    c4 c c c
    \compressMMRests {
      \once \override MultiMeasureRestScript.parent-alignment-X = 1
      R1*17
      \fermata
      }
    c4 c c c
  }
}
```

produces

[image: Multi-measure rest with fermata at right edge of rest symbol]

See also: LilyPond Manual, 3.1.79 [MultiMeasureRestScript](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/internals/multimeasurerestscript)

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
\compressMMRests {
  R1*17 
  \once\override Score.RehearsalMark.self-alignment-X = #1.4
  \once\override Score.RehearsalMark.break-visibility = #begin-of-line-invisible
  \once\override Score.RehearsalMark.font-size = #0
  \once\override Score.RehearsalMark.padding = #0
  \mark \markup \musicglyph #"scripts.ufermata"
}
```

This abuses Marks, but it has the advantage that it will work even if the rests are not compressed.

Comment: Why abuse rehearsal marks now that we have text marks?

Comment: @jeanas Did not know what version the OP is on, so played it safe.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be this:

```
\version "2.24.1"

\compressMMRests {
  c'4 4 4 4
  R1*17
  \once \set Staff.caesuraType = #'()
  \caesura\tweak self-alignment-X #1.5 \fermata
  c'4 4 4 4
}
```

[image: music output]

It's similar to @Aaron's answer, but the alignment is done relative to the bar line, not relative to the right edge of the compressed MM rest. In particular, this will work both with compressed and expanded MM rests.